# Event delegation - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I though it is possible to listen all the events on document but following code is not working. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
$(document).on('test', function() { 
    console.log('document is listening for test event'); 
});
```

and then fire test event from an object:

```
  var obj = {};
  $(obj).trigger('test'); //nothing happens, why?
```

Shouldn't above code fire function associated to test event on `document`?

Comment: `obj` is not part of document.

Comment: So everything in browser is child of window but not document?

Comment: @user2855314 The DOM is not part of ECMAScript. And the `document` is a Object so how can `Object` be a child of `document`?

Comment: Is something wrong with this question, why downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, what you have isn't event delegation, that's just a regular event binding to the `document`. In order for an event handler on something - such as the document - to fire, that event has to be triggered on that element - either by triggering it on that element directly or by triggering an event that propagates ("bubbles") up the DOM to that element.

Your example doesn't work because your object `obj` isn't part of the `document`, so the `test` event is never triggered on the document.

Answer (score 1):

This will fire your event:

```
$(document).trigger('test');
```

Or any child of `document`:

```
$('body').trigger('test');
```

Your empty object `obj` is not `document` or a child of `document` so will not fire the event bound on `document`